# get max value occurred within every 10 minute of a day

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `pointdb` containing columns:

```
SOLAR_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0
LOAD_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0
timestamp
```

It contains every second wise data. I wanted to display max of `SOLAR_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0` and max of `LOAD_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0` occurring within every 10 minute interval. For that I have written a query as follows:

```
Collapse | Copy Code

SELECT max(SOLAR_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0) AS Solar,max(LOAD_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0) AS Load, (DATEPART(MINUTE, [timestamp]) % 10) AS [Minutes]
FROM pointdb WHERE CONVERT(varchar,[timestamp],101) in('03/07/2014')
GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, [timestamp]) % 10)
```

But it is not giving right output.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
SELECT max(SOLAR_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0) AS Solar,
       max(LOAD_ACTIVE_POWER_G_VAL0) AS Load, 
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, timestamp)/10*10, 0) AS [Minutes] 
FROM pointdb
```

```
WHERE CONVERT(varchar,[timestamp],101) in('03/07/2014')
```

```
WHERE [timestamp] >= '20140307' AND [timestamp] < '20140308'
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, timestamp)/10*10, 0)
```

The part

```
DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, timestamp)/10*10, 0)
```

should round down to the start of the 10 minute period.
If you leave out `/10*10`, you get it to the nearest 1 minute period.

Comment: The where could really be improved to `WHERE [timestamp] >= '20140307' AND [timestamp] < '20140308'` to save yourself from a table scan - if there is an index on `timestamp`.

Comment: ahh, so that was what the convoluted WHERE clause was about. :-)
Yes, make sure that you fix your where clause as ypercube suggests.
@ypercube; thank you for formatting my answer. I'll try to get the same code-block as you used. Much clearer.

Comment: You can edit your answer. Comments may be deleted and are not visible to search engines.